# Autosizing a grid column to take up remaining space in parent

Tags: wpf, grid

In WPF, I am having a heck of a time trying to get a grid to size properly.

I have the following layout for my grid:

```
<ItemsControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="3"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem is that Width="Auto" seems to be sizing that column to the width of the content, and not filling out the extra space in the parent container. This leaves the rest of the columns all unaligned, and ugly blank space at the end of each row.

I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't seem to find a method to fit the column appropriately.

Or is there a better control for the job?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`*` means fill or share.  If you had two with `*` then they would share the width evenly.

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems I found a solution after a bit more tinkering around.

The problem was: `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>`

This was causing the column to fit to the content. I changed it to: `<ColumnDefinition />`

This causes the column to fit to the empty space left in the parent container, regardless of content size.

Comment: That translates to `Width="*"`. See @Blam's answer for a little more detail

Comment: Mhh doesn't seem to work in my case, Button is still only as big as it's Text.

Comment: Doesn't work if the content width is bigger than the column.