# Is it possible to edit a cell with a CheckBox and TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, datagrid

I have the following coding where I bind a CheckBox and TextBlock into one `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Would it be possible for me to edit the cell with the checkbox and textbox when I click on the cell itself to edit the text inside of it? I still want to be able to set my CheckBox to true or false at the same time as editing the text within the textblock.

Here is my coding:

```
  private void btnFeedbackSelectSupplier_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        DataGridTemplateColumn columnFeedbackSupplier = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        columnFeedbackSupplier.Header = "Supplier";
        columnFeedbackSupplier.CanUserReorder = true;
        columnFeedbackSupplier.CanUserResize = true;
        columnFeedbackSupplier.IsReadOnly = false;

        //My stack panel where I will host the two elements 
        var stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        stackPanel.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

        DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();

        //Where I create my checkbox
        FrameworkElementFactory factoryCheck = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        Binding bindCheck = new Binding("TrueFalse");
        bindCheck.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        factoryCheck.SetValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, bindCheck);
        stackPanel.AppendChild(factoryCheck);

        //Where I create my textblock
        FrameworkElementFactory factoryText = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        Binding bindText = new Binding("Supplier");
        bindText.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        factoryText.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, bindText);
        stackPanel.AppendChild(factoryText);

        cellTemplate.VisualTree = stackPanel;
        columnFeedbackSupplier.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;

        DataGridTextColumn columnFeedbackSupplierItem = new DataGridTextColumn();
        columnFeedbackSupplier.Header = (cmbFeedbackSelectSupplier.SelectedItem as DisplayItems).Name;

        dgFeedbackAddCost.SelectAll();

        IList list = dgFeedbackAddCost.SelectedItems as IList;
        IEnumerable<ViewQuoteItemList> items = list.Cast<ViewQuoteItemList>();

        var collection = (from i in items
                          let a = new ViewQuoteItemList { Item = i.Item, Supplier = i.Cost, TrueFalse = false }
                          select a).ToList();

        dgFeedbackSelectSupplier.Columns.Add(columnFeedbackSupplier);
        dgFeedbackSelectSupplier.ItemsSource = collection;
    }
```

My example of how it looks now and how I would like to edit that `R12` value inside the cell, while still being able to set the checkbox to true or false.

[image]

Comment: Why don't use  `TextBox` instead of `TextBlock`?

Comment: I knew someone would ask this question :P Because the `TextBox` looks silly, as it does  not want to expand the full width of my column length

Comment: just set the property `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` of `TextBox`

Comment: `factoryText.Text = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;` like this? 0_o

Comment: if `factoryText` is `TextBox`, then `textBox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for my original question, YES you can edit the cell with a `CheckBox` inside, but instead of a `TextBlock` I used a `TextBox` and I changed my the following coding from my question:

```
var stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
stackPanel.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);//Delete this line
```

To

```
var dockPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DockPanel));
```

Because a `StackPanel` does not have support for certain elements (like a `TextBox`) to fill the remaining available space, where a `DockPanel` does have support for it.

And then I added this line to make my `TextBox` fill the remaining space availble

```
factoryText.SetValue(TextBox.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch);
```

Hope this will help someone else out there :)

Comment: sorry that I did not test my answer. I've edited my answer:).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use `TextBlock` instead of `TextBox` ? If you want to expand the full width of my column length, then just set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` like that:

```
FrameworkElementFactory factoryText = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
factoryText.Text = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
```

**Update:**

And put your `TextBox` into `Grid` or `DockPanel;` [as Zach Johnson says that `StackPanel` is meant for "stacking" things even outside the visible region, so it won't allow you to fill remaining space in the stacking dimension.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737077/wpf-textbox-wont-fill-in-stackpanel)

Comment: Your answer will not work as you have to do it like this:                                  `factoryText.SetValue(TextBox.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch);` and change the `StackPanel` to a `DockPanel`, because the StackPanel does not support the element like the TextBox to fill the remaining space available ;)

Comment: @CareTaker22 sorry that I've not tested my solution. I've edited my answer.