# UserControl won't stretch into StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, oxyplot

I have a Dashboard with diffrent tiles. In my last tile, I included a OxyPlot-Chart as a UserControl. But it's the only UserControl that won't stretch. It renders with Height = 0. I just get the result by setting the height to a fix size - Auto also does not affect anything. Also remove the "d" size of the UserControl.

xaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Background="{StaticResource TileBackground}" Margin="10">
   <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF1E7DBF" Margin="0,0,0,5">
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="24H-PERFORMANCE" Margin="30,10,30,10"
                           TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI SemiBold" Foreground="White" FontSize="26" />
   </DockPanel>
   <local:DayPerformance />
</StackPanel>
```

userControl:

```
<Grid>
   <oxy:PlotView x:Name="performanceMonitor" Model="{Binding performancePlot}" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: As a quick answer `StackPanel` will autosize itself to content. You have (must?) to use another container, e.g. `Grid` with row definitions to be able to stretch content. Not sure which duplicate address this issue the best, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737077/1997232) is one.

Comment: Ok I will try. In my other tiles I also use StackPanel and loading UserControls - here it works fine.

Comment: No it can't be true. Vertical `StackPanel` will autosize its content `Height` (I used a bit wrongly worded explanation in previous comment), despite `StackPanel` is stretched. The only way to influence `Height` of its children is to set `Height` explicitly. Simply use `Grid` with star-height row as container for usercontrol.